# What is R60, R72, and MINE file?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, svn, visual-studio-2012

I was building a DataAccessLayer using C# in VS 2012, and in my project, there are three files which I don't know how to deal with.

```
DataAccessLayer.csproj.mine
DataAccessLayer.csproj.r60
DataAccessLayer.csproj.r72
```

What are they? How should I deal with them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They are files created from your repository that the code is saved in.  You did an update and when you try to commit your files you will get a `commit failed` probably.  When you `diff` the files, it will use the `.mine .r60 .r72` files to bring up the differences between each revision (.r60, r72) and your file (.mine) and allow you to do something like `Keep all changes in mine`.

In order to get rid of the `commit failed` error messages, find the original file, update it with the correct changes, and when finished right click it and `Mark as resolved` and `commit`.  This will get rid of those files.

Comment: I forgot to mention I was using SVN. Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 2):

Those files are related to version control (.mine is your file, .rX come from revision number X). You should try to merge them using your version controlling tool if you have one. If you don't have one and got those files by copying a project, you can possibly delete the .r files and rename DataAccessLayer.csproj.mine in DataAccessLayer.csproj (unless you already have DataAccessLayer.csproj - just keep it and delete the other then). Edit: And if it causes problems, try merging them manually (using a text editor for example) before keeping the final file.